# How do I bootstrap Automapper with Nancy in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper, autofac, nancy

How do I bootstrap Automapper with Nancy in .Net Core? I am using the Automapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection nuget package, whereby I call `services.AddAutoMapper();` in `Startup.ConfigureServices`. The profile within my Nancy assembly is registered, but profiles in external assemblies are not. I don't have this problem with Asp.Net Core.

I'm using Nancy v2.0.0-clinteastwood, Automapper 7.0.1, Automapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 5.0.1 and .Net Core v2.1.

My DI container is Autofac v4.3

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu yes, maybe I have to explicitly specify the external assemblies. What's interesting is that I don't have to do that with an asp.net core web api project.

Comment: Maybe they're just already loaded.